# New York strip roast came out like beef jerky

Tags: meat, beef, roast

OMGosh. Please help! Was I supposed to cover the New York strip roast with liquid? I RUINED dinner because there are no IP instructions so I used the instructions for “beef roast” and “steak”. I’m so upset because I just got the darn thing and was so excited to make this for my husband and it has the texture of beef jerky. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi there.  We don't reply directly via tweet. On this site, you ask questions and the community answers them.  Your question does not specify how you cooked your steak, but I assume IP means insta-pot.  Really, the last place you want to put a strip roast.  Anyway, you can first begin by searching the site using the search bar, to see if your question has been asked and answered.  If it has not, the clearer and more specific you are, the better.

Comment: Please check [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how the site works, and [edit] your question to make it easier to answer.

Comment: It’s too bad you don’t use the internet, because using Google I easily found many excellent recipes for New York strop roast.

Answer (score 4):

You made 2 mistakes.

1. A pressure cooker (like InstaPot) relies on water to make steam to create pressure.  You should not put a roast in the pressure cooker without adding liquid.
2. A pressure cooker is ideal for breaking down collagen in cheap, tough cuts of meat to make them tender.  NY Strip is a premium cut that is already tender - just roast it in the oven.